# .NET "Push" technologies?

Tags: .net, push-notification, push

I am designing a new project and I am trying to figure out ways to push data/events from a server application to a client application (ie a WPF application).

The two I know of are:

- Pub/Sub (ie [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/))
- [Full Duplex WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx)

Are there other solutions for the server to talk to the client?  If so what are they?

Answer (score 10):

[Query Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx) might be useful ,

> Query notifications were introduced in
>   SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server Native
>   Client. Built upon the Service Broker
>   infrastructure introduced in SQL
>   Server 2005, query notifications allow
>   applications to be notified when data
>   has changed. This feature is
>   particularly useful for applications
>   that provide a cache of information
>   from a database, such as a Web
>   application, and need to be notified
>   when the source data is changed.

Also please read this topic :
[Receiving Database Change Notifications Using the WCF Service Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788500%28BTS.10%29.aspx)

---

In ASP.NET applications :
Use [Pokein](http://pokein.codeplex.com/) ASP.NET comet AJAX library (Reverse-AJAX Server push)

> PokeIn gives you an enhanced JSON
>   functionality to make your server side
>   objects available in client side.
>   Simply, it is a Reverse Ajax library
>   which makes it easy to call JavaScript
>   functions from C#/VB.NET and to call
>   C#/VB.NET functions from JavaScript.
>   It has numerous features like event
>   ordering, resource management,
>   exception handling, marshaling, Ajax
>   upload control, mono compatibility,
>   WCF & .NET Remoting integration and
>   scalable server push.
>
> PokeIn is compatible with Mono and All
>   the .Net versions(>1.1). 
>   [image]
>
> Above diagram shows, how PokeIn
>   generates dynamic JavaScript codes
>   from a .NET class to provide
>   interaction on both side.
>
> PokeIn organizes connections and
>   generates server side object instances
>   for each client. So, you can be sure
>   about the interactions with specific
>   target. PokeIn follows the connection
>   state of each client to tell you one
>   of your users has just disconnected.
>   Also, It groups client side
>   connections by server side session
>   ids. Thus, you know how many views
>   active on a single session.
>
> PokeIn creates a channel between the
>   client and server side static
>   resource. It simply manages resources
>   which specific to a client session
>   and/or application wide.
>
> PokeIn provides secure channels (view
>   specific decoding and session/view
>   cross check) . Also, it gives you to
>   control for communication handlers.
>   So, you may add some extra security
>   controls into these layers.
>
> PokeIn is a comprehensive solution. It
>   has many features that any web
>   application may need. It has been used
>   in many projects like an online
>   spreadsheet application to browser
>   based games.
>
> Important Notice PokeIn definer class
>   feature is provided to make your
>   communication needs between the client
>   and server in a solid way. Make sure
>   your implementation efficiently uses
>   it.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of web solutions are outlined at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29.  Of course, these only apply for web applications, but this list may still be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use any web transfer, simply increase the timeout from the caller. Then at the server, simply block until you have data to send.